# Application load considerations, use what you get vs. not all at once

Tags: sql-server, performance, windows, odbc

## General question:

Should I as an application use all resources I can get and thrust the OS schedeuler **or** should I already do some load considerations for the OS. If so, what metric should I use?

## Background

I've developed an application/importer that loads measurement data from files all over your network shares, converts them into one common format and then uploads it in the database scheme I design. A huge part of the data is already been measured and only a fraction of the amount will be added over time, by measuring tools. So to get new data fast into the database, I'm concurrent watching about 15 directories for new files and if so, start an upload with the actual uploader I've written, which also uses 5 threads and ODBC connection pooling to upload the parsed data.

#### The loader

The loader is a C written application using plain ODBC. I gets the file name passed as arguments and opens a fixed count (5) of odbc database connections. Then the parser start to read the data file line by line, checks that only as much threads are running the fixed connection count, and either creates a new thread which uploads the line to the db or waits until one finishes. Repeat till EOF. Sounds pretty stupid now. (Did it over a year ago, may change)

### Problem is

This lead to a 100% load on the windows server for the first minutes, because 6 million rows are to imported. My administrator of the virtual machines is yelling at me that he get's alarms from the hyper visor software, because one VM is running on the edge and tells me to teach my application some self throttling, which is according to him, best practice.

Comment: Tell your VM guy to not worry - it's perfectly normal, and even expected for a machine to be able to pin the CPU.  I mean why else would you ever need to get a faster CPU?  seems silly to me to worry if a VM is pinned for a short(ish) period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just batch it up into values (1,1),  (2,2)    ....
There is going to be a sweet spot but anywhere from 100 to 10,000 values in a batch

A producer consumer is good here where you have multiple producers watching directories and then one consumer writing to the database.

I do exactly this were I am parsing down some files for words and load them into a database.